# How to ajax() post more than one JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I currently have a `$.getJSON()` call, which gets a `JSON` string from one specific url. Simplified code is like this and it is working fine:

```
$.getJSON("myURL",function(data){
    var receivedJSON = data;
});
```

The `JSON` data looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"jerry"},{"id":2,"name":"tom"}]
```

Now, in my program, I have a table that takes user input and when user click submit, it will do a `ajax` call and serialize the user input into `json` data and pass to the back-end, simplified html code is like this:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The javascript that handles grabbing the user input data is like this:

```
function() {
var tableObj = $('table tbody tr').map(function(i) {
                                       var row = {};
                                       $(this).find('td').each(function(i){
                                        var rowName = header[i];
                                        row[rowName] =$(this).find("input").val();
                                   });
                return row;
                }).get();
```

So the `var` `tableObj` contains data from the userInput that needed to be passed to the back end and it is working.

The working version of `ajax` function that handles passing user input data from the table to the back-end is like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "myPOST_URL",
        type : 'POST',
        data : JSON.stringify(tableObj),
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 }); //end ajax
```

Now, my question is, if I want to not only POST the `tableObj` data through `.ajax`, but also want to include the `json` data that I received from `$.getJSON`(in this example it is: `var receivedJSON`), what can I do to make this happen?

Comment: Create a JSON object congaing both `receivedJSON` and table data.

Comment: Wrap them in a single object. Your backend will have to change to expect this new object and separate them again.

Comment: LIke this: `JSON.stringify({ table: tableObj, received: receivedJSON})`

Comment: @Barmar did you what suggested. works, thanks

Comment: @Barmar Great solution. Please make your comment into an answer for credit, upvoting and esp. for future readers (like myself)

Comment: Someone else already posted a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
   $.getJSON("myURL",function(data){
      $.post("myPOST_URL",{receivedJSON: data, formData: $("#formular").serializeArray()});
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formular">
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
</form>
```